# WPF TextBox.DataBindings using PowerShell

Tags: c#, wpf, powershell, xaml, data-binding

I'm trying to bind a WPF TextBox with my datatable 
I keep getting the following error

> You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression

I'm not sure if I'm missing an argument that I need to pass or it's related to something else.

Here is my XAML code

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Name="TextBox_PageShareModels_EmailSubject" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" FontSize="15" FontWeight="Normal"
                         VerticalAlignment="Center" ToolTip="Subject of your email." Margin="0,5,5,5"/>
```

In Powershell, I'm creating my datatable, then i'm trying to bind textbox to one of the columns (result in the datatable is always one record)
Here is the powershell script 
The binding is on the last line of the script

```
    $Global:DataSet.Tables.Add($Global:dtEmailMessages)
    $Global:dtEmailMessages.PrimaryKey = $Global:dtEmailMessages.Columns["ComposerEmail"]

    $Global:dtEmailMessages.Columns["Subject"].AllowDBNull = $true 
    $Global:dtEmailMessages.Columns["Body"].AllowDBNull = $true 

    $Global:dtEmailMessages.Columns["ModifiedBy"].ReadOnly = $true 
    $Global:dtEmailMessages.Columns["ModifiedBy"].AllowDBNull = $False 
    $Global:dtEmailMessages.Columns["ModifiedBy"].DefaultValue = $Env:USERNAME 

    $Global:dtEmailMessages.Columns["ModifiedOn"].ReadOnly = $true 
    $Global:dtEmailMessages.Columns["ModifiedOn"].AllowDBNull = $False 
    $Global:dtEmailMessages.Columns["ModifiedOn"].DefaultValue = (Get-Date -Format s)    

    $TextBox_PageShareModels_EmailSubject.DataBindings.Add("Text",$Global:dtEmailMessages,"Subject")
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Not sure, but shouldn't that be `$TextBox_PageShareModels_EmailSubject.DataBindings.Add("Subject", $Global:dtEmailMessages, "$Global:dtEmailMessages.Subject")` ?

Comment: Hi Theo, that didn't work unfortunately :-( 
I'm getting the same error and I feel like the syntax is incorrect either

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer after many trial and errors!

```
    #Bind datatable column to WPF TextBox using Powershell
    $Binding = New-Object System.Windows.Data.Binding        
    $Binding.Path = "[Subject]"
    $Binding.Source = $Global:dtEmailMessages.DefaultView
    $Binding.Mode = [System.Windows.Data.BindingMode]::OneWay
    [System.Windows.Data.BindingOperations]::SetBinding($TextBox_PageShareModels_EmailSubject,[System.Windows.Controls.TextBox]::TextProperty,$Binding)
```